# Loop each x elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

What is the best way to show a list with 20 images in rows of 5? Or, in other words, how do I clean up this ugly snippet?

```
<div class="row">
  <% @images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
    <% if index != 0 && index % 5 == 0 %>
      </div><div class="row">
    <% end %>
    <%= image_tag image.url %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003142) to loop through the images in rows of five images each:

```
<% @images.each_slice(5) do |row| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% row.each do |image| %>
      <%= image_tag image.url %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Cool, this is a much cleaner solution. Thanks Pär!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `in_groups_of` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html which also has other options.